# Fetch only Folders name into ListView from SD Card

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-sdcard

How to fetch only folders name from SD card into a `ListView`?

In one of my Church Application, I am allowing user to create an event (example: Phase-I Church - Evening Prayer_Part1), and then creating a folder with same name into

```
SD Card/Church Application/EventNameFolders
```

So now my target is to show all folders name from Church Application into `ListView`.

Comment: Please don't abuse formatting, and next time, please provide what you have done (example: code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Church Application/";

File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // in here, you can add directory names into an ArrayList and populate your ListView.
        your_array_list.add(inFile.getName());
    }
}

 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 your_array_list );

         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**Delete empty folders**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Church Application/";

File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // If this folder is empty, delete it.
        if (inFile.listFiles().length == 0) {
            inFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Delete empty folders and Display only folders which are not empty**

```
private ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Church Application/";

File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // If this folder is empty, delete it.
        if (inFile.listFiles().length == 0) {
            inFile.delete();
         // If not, add to ArrayList 
        } else if (inFile.listFiles().length >= 1) {
            your_array_list.add(inFile.getName());
        } 
    }
}

 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 your_array_list );

         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: last small question, what if i also want to delete folder which is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

```
File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


        for (File f : file)
        {
            if (f.isDirectory()) { 
                 file[] innerFiles = f.listFiles();

                 for(int i=0; i< innerFiles.length;i++){
                   Log.i("Name", innerFiles[i].getPath() + "");
                 }
        }

            if (f.isFile()) {your code}
        }
```

Comment: can you show me the way how to show it on list as well

Comment: That innerfile array contains  all folder value from your sdcard,based on that you can retrieve corresponding folder value accordingly.